# Forcibly stop the execution of the function in the cfc component

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

Does anyone know how I can forcibly stop a function execution in the cfc component if it works for more than a certain time? Either it may be piece of code, not a whole function, i.e. if it has completed in 5 seconds, I take some actions, otherwise others.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Run the function in a `<cfthread>` with its attribute `timeout` being set to the maximum time to wait before killing the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to stop an arbitrary piece of code is to run it in a separate thread and then terminating after a set amount of time. This can be done by calling out to a separate page with a request timeout set or using cfthread.

For example with thread...
(Note.... as Alex pointed out you can use timeout on cfthread)

```
<cfthread action="run" name="runForLimitedTime">
    ... code, call to function, etc ...
</cfthread>

<cfset sleep(5000) />

<cfif cfthread.runForLimitedTime.status eq "COMPLETED">
    <cfthread action="join" />
<cfelse>
    <cfthread action="terminate" name="runForLimitedTime" />
</cfif>
```

Alternatively with a separate page...

```
<!--- calling page --->

<cfset error = false />
<cftry>
    <cfhttp url="pageSetupForSpecificCall.cfm?timeout=5" throwonerror="true" />
    <cfcatch>
        <cfset error = true />
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfif error>
    something
<cfelse>
    something else
</cfif>


<!--- pageSetupForSpecificCall.cfm --->

<cfsetting requesttimeout="#url.timeout#" />

...do things...
```

Comment: I think the `cfhttp` approach shows more promise than `cfthread`.

Comment: @DanBracuk any particular reason for that opinion?

Comment: my opinion is based on the fact that the timeout is included in code that runs consecutively as opposed to concurrently.  With `cfthread`, I'm not sure if the parent template can do anything about the execution time of the thread.  I even have doubts about the `cfhttp` approach.  The timeout setting in the pageSetupForSpecificCall.cfm page might override the timeout setting of the calling page.  I'm now retired and don't have CF installed at home, so my thoughts are based on what I remember.  I am not able to quickly test any theories I might have.

Comment: @DanBracuk the purpose of cfthread is to run code concurrently in a separate thread

Comment: I understand that.  However, the only way I can think of using another thread to achieve what the OP wants is to capture the starting tickcount of that page, and then check for elapsed execution time at various points of the page.  However, I don't see it being reliable.